# Performance testing for lock free data structures

Tags: java, benchmarking, performance-testing, lock-free

I am working on a lock-free self-organizing list and I was looking for some benchmarks too which I could compare my results or some program with which i could test the performance of my algorithms.

The code is written in Java and i will need to run multiple scenarios :

1. Heavy Read: 90% search, 9% add, 1% remove
2. Mixed: 60% search, 15% add, 15% remove
3. Heavy modifying: 33% search, 33% add, 33% remove

---

Just to be clear my question is:

If anyone knows some benchmarks or performance measurement tools where I could compare my results?

Comment: Ok, good luck, you have my permission. Did you have a question? What have you tried? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: You should test using multiple threads as this can make a big difference. Do you have a view on a) how many threads you are likely to use? b) what is the level of concurrency i.e. typically how many threads will be using the structure at the same time?

Comment: I was thinking in a range of 1000 threads which are started at the same time. Using Junit and TestNG i already made some smaller test for different scenarios but i do not know to what can i compare them to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try benchmarking against other lock-free list implementations in the benchmark suites such as

https://github.com/gramoli/synchrobench

https://github.com/LPD-EPFL/ASCYLIB

Among others